# ImageMagick convert: UnrecognizedMorphologyMethod

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I saw in documentation of Imagemagick this command:

`convert qc.gif  -morphology Thinning:-1 Skeleton  qc2.gif`

But echo this error:

```
convert: UnrecognizedMorphologyMethod `Thinning' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1957.
```

But when I list the commands avaliable (`convert -list command`) it shows:

```
+morphology
-morphology
```

Answer (score 1):

I updated Imagemagick to 6.6.9-1 version and now it works.